# Село Киевка — склонение топонима

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Склоняется ли топоним **Киевка** в сочетании с родовым словом "село"?
Привет из *села Киевк**а*** или из *села Киевк**и***?
Правило: "Географическое название, употребленное с родовыми наименованиями город, село, деревня, хутор, река и др., выступающее в функции приложения, согласуется с определяемым словом, то есть склоняется, если топоним русского, славянского происхождения..."
Опираясь на это правило, считаю, что склонять корректно. В официальных документах по-разному. Чаще не склоняют. Объясните, пожалуйста, как будет верно.

Answer (score 3):

Слово *село* среднего рода, *Киевка* - женского рода. Поэтому название села не склоняем во избежание недопонимания, ср.: ***от села Киевки (село Киевка или Киевки?):***

*в селе Киевка, от села Киевка* и т.п.

[Склонение географических названий](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)

**Географические названия в сочетании с родовым словом обычно не склоняются в следующих случаях:**

...
**когда род обобщающего нарицательного слова и топонима не совпадают: на реке Енисей, у реки Хопёр, в деревне Парфёнок (однако: в городе Туле, из города Москвы)...**

Обратите внимание на слово **обычно**. Это означает, что правило нестрогое.